# ¿Como hago un INSERT en MySQL desde un codigo PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

llevo un rato ya intentando hacer un INSERT de un registro pero no me deja.
El tipo de dato que estoy intentando insertar, en la base de datos es un DATETIME, por lo que el formato intuyo que es "Y-M-D H:m:s".
El código que estoy tratando es el siguiente:

```
$stmt = $BBDD->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(nick, nombre, apellidos, contrasenna, email, telefono, foto_perfil, intereses, fecha_alta, bloqueado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssi', $nick, $nombre, $apellidos, $contrasenna, $email, $telefono, $directorio, "ciclismo", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 0);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

El valor que me devuelve date("Y-m-d H:i:s") es un string con por ejemplo "2020-04-01 17:51:32", pero me sale el siguiente error a la hora de realizar la consuta:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 9 by reference
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que guardarlo en una variable y pasar la variable,  ya que, como dice el error `bind_param` no permite pasar valores por referencia, y eso incluye los valores que devuelven las funciones como `date()`, así como los otros valores que intentas pasar a mano.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*Definimos en variable los tres valores*/
$intereses="ciclismo";
$fecha=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$bloqueado=0;

$stmt = $BBDD->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(nick, nombre, apellidos, contrasenna, email, telefono, foto_perfil, intereses, fecha_alta, bloqueado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssi', $nick, $nombre, $apellidos, $contrasenna, $email, $telefono, $directorio, $intereses, $fecha, $bloqueado);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, por no solo por lo da insertar el date(), si no por las otras dos que estaba metiendo a pelo. Me estaba ofuscando con que era lo del date() solamente... Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cierto @Marcos. No estaba seguro de si los valores hardcoded también, estuve haciendo pruebas y efectivamente, tampoco los deja pasar directamente, hay que pasarlo todo en variables.